# Generating random background for a game

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

i develop a 2D game with OpenGL (OpenTK) and C#. 
I like to have a random background composed of stars and fog.

In the middle of my projection is a starship. 
The starship can move in any direction. 
The background will generated dynamically in any direction too.
My problem is the performance. I`m rendering 48000 vertices
(6000 Rectangles with an .png texture) for a small
area. And the area will grow because my starship is moving.
MY PC: CPU 4 Core x 2300mhz, GeForce 9800 GTX+ and its still
running slow. Is it normal ?

There a 1 Solutions in my mind. Render area and create a bitmap for backgroundtexture.

Maybe you have an better solution. Or you can tell me the disadvantages
creating dynamically a background texture.

Answer (score 1):

Let you filed of view be 4x4.

So you should render a picture 5x5 composed from pices of 1x1 and center it on your screen.

Than, when your starship moves you should generate a pice of picture 1x5 (5 small pices with size of 1x1) and put it in front of your ship, and you should delete a pice of picture from the other direction. If ship moves left, you should put a new pice of space on the left and remove a pice from the right. etc.

Comment: thats what i do right now. but without pictures. i generate real stars and fog. the solution to build a picture of the background was already on my mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want a scrolling texture background, you can just modify the texture coordinates based on the starship's position. To make it look more unique, you could use a few transparent textures and layer them, which will give you a parallax effect.

As for the stars, I'd use `GL_POINTS`. Once the star 'falls off' the edge of the viewable screen, make it appear on the other side. Once again you can have them more at different rates because as we know, stars aren't all the same distance away.

I'm sorry I can't be more specific, but I'm at work.

Comment: Sorry the scrolling texture solution is not for me. The gamer need to have the feeling the background is not repeating and always the same if the starship move back to position.

Comment: Well the solution isn't to draw the whole universe. If you are separating it into quads, then you should just draw the ones that are on screen. Rendering 48000 vertices are too much just for a background

Comment: thats right, changed it. the collection grows to big. so every quad have a collection of stars and will be added to my render batch only while visible. I can not accept your because you write something different as answer.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer for your own question, and then accept it. This will help others who are reading this in the future, and improve your reputation